# Why would a high centre of gravity be beneficial under traction for an F1 car?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I’ve been watching a lot of racing recently, and one of the spectators said:

‘a high centre of gravity is beneficial under traction for an F1 car’

Why is this true? Is it even true? And what does under traction mean here please?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.formula1-dictionary.net/centre_of_gravity.html the centre of gravity will always be kept as low as possible. Perhaps s/he means that with a high centre of gravity, acceleration will cause weight transfer to the rear wheels and improve grip which might be a good thing for that one situation (when accelerating in a straight line). The downside would be the loss of steering grip and the opposite effect during braking when the back-end would loose grip. By keeping the CoG close to the ground weight transfer during cornering is minimised also so all four wheels grip.